# Is there a way to "notify" when you hit the hourly limit?

Tags: c#, twitter, tweetinvi

I'm currently looking at the docs for TweetInvi and I looked into the `RateLimit` class.
And I've been trying to implement it and I don't know if it's the lack of understanding for Twitter or the limits but I can't seem to find a way to send a `notification` in terms of a console message saying "Hey, you've hit the hourly limit, it will reset in x minutes..." or something similar in that fasion.

I was looking at this example which you can also find in the docs.

```
TweetinviEvents.QueryBeforeExecute += (sender, args) =>
{
    var queryRateLimits = RateLimit.GetQueryRateLimit(args.QueryURL);

    // Some methods are not RateLimited. Invoking such a method will result in the queryRateLimits to be null
    if (queryRateLimits != null)
    {
        if (queryRateLimits.Remaining > 0)
        {
            // We have enough resource to execute the query
            return;
        }

        // Strategy #1 : Wait for RateLimits to be available
        Console.WriteLine("Waiting for RateLimits until : {0}", queryRateLimits.ResetDateTime.ToLongTimeString());
        Thread.Sleep((int)queryRateLimits.ResetDateTimeInMilliseconds);

        // Strategy #2 : Use different credentials
        var alternateCredentials = TwitterCredentials.CreateCredentials("", "", "", "");
        var twitterQuery = args.TwitterQuery;
        twitterQuery.OAuthCredentials = alternateCredentials;

        // Strategy #3 : Cancel Query
        args.Cancel = true;

        // Strategy #4 : Implement yours!
    }
};
```

How would I implement it and actually get a notification out of it when I try to send a tweet out saying something along the lines of "Hey, slow there buddy you've hit the limites please wait (the amount of time left)"

If that's even possible with that wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

See below example and i hope that helps.

```
public class TwitterManager
{
    private readonly ITwitterCredentials _credentials;
    private bool _isRateLimited;

    public TwitterManager()
    {
        _credentials = Auth.SetUserCredentials("", "", "", "");
        TweetinviEvents.QueryBeforeExecute += (sender, args) =>
        {
            var queryRateLimit = RateLimit.GetQueryRateLimit(args.QueryURL);
            if (queryRateLimit != null)
            {
                if (queryRateLimit.Remaining > 0)
                     return;
                else
                    _isRateLimited = true;
            }
        };

    }

    public void GetTweets() {
        UserTimelineParameters userTimelineParameters = new UserTimelineParameters();
        userTimelineParameters.MaximumNumberOfTweetsToRetrieve = 50;
        try
        {
            var tweets = Auth.ExecuteOperationWithCredentials(_credentials, () =>
            {
                return Timeline.GetUserTimeline("cnn", userTimelineParameters);
            });

            if (_isRateLimited)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Request rate limit has been exceeded. Please try again later.");
            }
            else if (tweets != null) {
                foreach (var item in tweets)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(item.FullText);
                }
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        catch (WebException wex)
        {
            var statusCode = -1;
            if (statusCode == TweetinviConsts.STATUS_CODE_TOO_MANY_REQUEST)
            {
                // The RateLimit is exhausted. Perform your code to manage it!
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Or you can look at this example .https://github.com/linvi/tweetinvi/issues/525#issuecomment-335008061